# How to enable the Broadcom wireless module in Dell new XPS 13 with kernel newer than 3.14?

Tags: broadcom

It is Broadcom BCM4352. The id is 14e4:43b1.
I could not get it work with opensource driver described in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx. And Broadcom driver cannot be compiled in 3.16+....
The system is Trusty.

Answer (score 1):

On my 3.16.0-xx system, the module builds and loads with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

I haven't the device, so I can test no further. Please let us know.

Comment: Sorry this took long. I got a "kernel not supported" error on 3.16.7....

Comment: What is your exact kernel? From the terminal: uname -r Thanks.

Comment: First of all, bmcwl-kernel-source works with the 3.13 kernel coming with Trusty. But after that, 3.15.10, 3.16.7, 3.17.8 (from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/), none is compile-able.

Comment: Just found the version in Utopic has added support of 3.18. Let me try.

Comment: Are you trying to compile source code or install the .deb in the Ubuntu repositories? The latter installs without error or even a single warning for me on the stock 3.16.0-30-generic linux-image.

Comment: Finally get it working. The driver in trusty-proposed repos is patched for 3.16+ kernel. Maybe you have enabled that so you did not get any trouble?

Comment: I did nothing extraordinary; just apt-get. If my answer was helpful, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If somebody else has this problem.

I tried installing the .deb a couple of times and got the driver in the "additional drivers" section in settings.
But when I clicked on the "Network" tab I still got "no network devices available".

What worked for me was to download the latest (not release) version of bcmwl-kernel-source:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/bcmwl-kernel-source/6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu0.1

I just upgraded to that and now it's working.